# Create new rows based on max rows of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm trying to create new data in a time series based on past data. For example I have player data here with each row being stats accumulated at a certain age. I want to create new row in the Dataframe where I increment the max age by one and then take the average of the `sa` and `ga` column from the two years before that.

Here is the data

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['Adam Wilcox', 8476330, 25, 14.0, 0.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 21, 129.0, 14.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 22, 322.0, 32.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 23, 343.0, 28.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 24, 530.0, 46.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 25, 237.0, 26.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 24, 120.0, 9.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 26, 585.0, 46.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 27, 832.0, 89.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 28, 168.0, 17.0]]

model_df = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                         columns=['player', 'player_id', 'season_age', 'sa', 'ga'])
```

For example what I would want to create is `['Al Montoya', 8471219, 29, 500, 53]` (remember the last two values is the average of the `sa` and `ga` columns from ages 28 and 27).

I've accomplished this using `iterrows` and creating a new Dataframe and appending like this:

```py
max_ages = model_df.groupby(['player', 'player_id'])[['season_age']].max().reset_index()
added_ages = []
for player in max_ages.iterrows():

    row = [player[1][0],
           player[1][1],
           player[1][2] + 1, 
           (model_df[(model_df['player_id'] == player[1][1]) &
                    (model_df['season_age'] == player[1][2] - 1)]['sa'].sum() +
           model_df[(model_df['player_id'] == player[1][1]) &
                    (model_df['season_age'] == player[1][2] - 2)]['sa'].sum())/2,
           (model_df[(model_df['player_id'] == player[1][1]) &
                    (model_df['season_age'] == player[1][2] - 1)]['ga'].sum() +
           model_df[(model_df['player_id'] == player[1][1]) &
                    (model_df['season_age'] == player[1][2] - 2)]['ga'].sum())/2
          ]
    added_ages.append(row)

added_ages_df = pd.DataFrame(added_ages, 
                             columns=['player', 'player_id', 'season_age', 'sa', 'ga'])
model_df = pd.concat([model_df, added_ages_df])
```

Obviously this is an adhoc solution that is very brittle, my question is if there is a built in way in `pandas` of doing this without using `iterrows`

The expected Dataframe would look like this easier to represent in list form

```
data = [['Adam Wilcox', 8476330, 25, 14.0, 0.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 21, 129.0, 14.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 22, 322.0, 32.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 23, 343.0, 28.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 24, 530.0, 46.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 25, 237.0, 26.0],
        ['Adin Hill', 8478499, 26, 502, 36],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 24, 120.0, 9.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 26, 585.0, 46.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 27, 832.0, 89.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 28, 168.0, 17.0],
        ['Al Montoya', 8471219, 29, 500, 53]]
```

Comment: Would an easier solution be to get your unique player names / ids, create a shell DataFrame with the age incrementing for each player from min age to max age whatever that is, then merge on your starting DataFrame and calculate your averages?  Is the aim that each player has the same min age to max age, or is the aim that you just want to add 2 additional rows for each player?

Comment: Kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function called `add_row` and pass it to a groupby. I'll assume that if there aren't two years of data for a player, you'll want the columns `sa` and `ga` to be populated with `NaN`:

```
def add_row(x):
    last_row = x.iloc[-1]
    last_row['season_age'] = last_row['season_age']+1
    if len(x) < 2:
        last_row['sa'], last_row['ga'] = float("nan"), float("nan")
        return x.append(last_row)
    else:
        last_row['sa'], last_row['ga'] = x[['sa','ga']].iloc[-2:].mean()
        return x.append(last_row)

new_model_df = model_df.groupby("player").apply(add_row).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_model_df
         player  player_id  season_age     sa    ga
0   Adam Wilcox    8476330          25   14.0   0.0
1   Adam Wilcox    8476330          26    NaN   NaN
2     Adin Hill    8478499          21  129.0  14.0
3     Adin Hill    8478499          22  322.0  32.0
4     Adin Hill    8478499          23  343.0  28.0
5     Adin Hill    8478499          24  530.0  46.0
6     Adin Hill    8478499          25  237.0  26.0
7     Adin Hill    8478499          26  383.5  36.0
8    Al Montoya    8471219          24  120.0   9.0
9    Al Montoya    8471219          26  585.0  46.0
10   Al Montoya    8471219          27  832.0  89.0
11   Al Montoya    8471219          28  168.0  17.0
12   Al Montoya    8471219          29  500.0  53.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Do some computation on the grouped object, and merge the result to the model_df:

```py
grouper = ['player', 'player_id']
grouped = model_df.groupby(grouper, sort = False)
tail = grouped.nth(-1) # get the last row per group
tail = tail.assign(season_age = tail.season_age + 1)
# get the average of the last two columns with rolling
# a second groupby is called here to get single rows per group
sa_ga = (group[['sa', 'ga']]
         .rolling(2)
         .mean()
         .groupby(grouper)
         .nth(-1)
         )

tail = tail.assign(**sa_ga).reset_index()

# final output
(pd.concat([model_df, tail])
   .sort_values(grouper, ignore_index = True)
)

         player  player_id  season_age     sa    ga
0   Adam Wilcox    8476330          25   14.0   0.0
1   Adam Wilcox    8476330          26    NaN   NaN
2     Adin Hill    8478499          21  129.0  14.0
3     Adin Hill    8478499          22  322.0  32.0
4     Adin Hill    8478499          23  343.0  28.0
5     Adin Hill    8478499          24  530.0  46.0
6     Adin Hill    8478499          25  237.0  26.0
7     Adin Hill    8478499          26  383.5  36.0
8    Al Montoya    8471219          24  120.0   9.0
9    Al Montoya    8471219          26  585.0  46.0
10   Al Montoya    8471219          27  832.0  89.0
11   Al Montoya    8471219          28  168.0  17.0
12   Al Montoya    8471219          29  500.0  53.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like below.

```
 df_new = df.shift()
 df_new['season_age'] = df['season_age'].max() +1
 df_new[['sa','ga']] = df[['sa','ga']].rolling(2).mean()
```

Comment: This does not work it overwrites the `season_age` column with all one value and does not calculate the added row for `Addin Hill` correctly